Cannot Run on Simulator with Flutter
I tried to use flutter run command in my flutter project folder and as you see I have the following error:
"Target debug_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Failed to extract arm64 for"...
I tried to google this issue but without much solutions... Can anyone help?

